# How do I zip files without compression using batch command

Tags: zip, ear, jdeveloper, winrar

I am writing a batch file in order to make an `.ear` file. Here is my code snippet:

```
winrar.exe a -afzip -m5 -ed -pTest -r -ep1 %earName%.ear %extractDest%*
```

This code compresses the including files which I don't want. How can I just add the files in the `"extractDest"` to the `.ear` file without compressing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line `zip` from [Info-Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/Zip.html#Downloads) as follows:

```
zip -rp0 earname.ear source_dir
```

`-0` means store and don't compress (`-r` recursive, `-p` preserve relative path).

Unlike `winrar`, Info-Zip is open source (no prompts to purchase), and its `zip` and `unzip` are true command-line utilities, and very small ones at that.

If you insist on using `winrar`, you must use option `-m0` (instead of `-m5`), which selects `0` (store) compression level.